# PHP - MONGODB - variable in query

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a problem with the use of PHP variables in MongoDB.

This query is ok:

```
$cursor1 = $collection->distinct(array('filename'=> array(['name'=>'pippo'])));
```

But this query does not work :

```
$cursor1 = $collection->distinct(array('filename'=> $whereClause));
```

where:

```
$whereClause = "array(['name'=>'pippo'])"
```

Why?

Comment: YOu are passing in a string instead of an array.

Comment: In your case $whereClause is a string from what i see, you surround the value with double quotes. Remove the double quotes and let $whereClause be an php array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When i remove the double quote i receive this error : Warning: MongoCollection::distinct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\prove\selectMongoDB.php on line 44

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.distinct.php), the [**`distinct`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) command returns a list of distinct values for the given key across a collection. In this case you want to give it two parameters  i.e. the key to use and the query which you want to pass in with the variable.

Consider the following example to demonstrate this

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient("localhost");
$collection = $m->selectDB("test")->selectCollection("Data");

$collection->insert(array("filename" => "bar.txt", "name" => "bar"));
$collection->insert(array("filename" => "foo", "name" => "pippo"));
$collection->insert(array("filename" => "foo", "name" => "test"));

$retval = $collection->distinct("filename");
var_dump($retval);

$whereClause = array("name" => "pippo");
$retval = $collection->distinct("filename", $whereClause);
var_dump($retval);

?>
```

---

Another approach is using the **[`command`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php)** method to issue the **[`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/)** command. Consider the following mongo shell example which finds all the distinct values for the key `"fieldname"` from all the documents in the `"Data"` collection:

```
db.runCommand({ distinct: "Data", key: "filename" })
```

This returns a document with a field named values that contains the distinct `filename` values:

```
{
   "values": [ "foo", "bar", "abc", "def" ],
   "stats": { ... },
   "ok" : 1
}
```

The next example returns the distinct values for the field `filename` from the "Data" collection with a query on documents whose `name` field is equal to `"pippo"`:

```
db.runCommand({ distinct: "Data", key: "filename", query: { name: "pippo"} })
```

which produces a similar document as above:

```
{
   "values": [ "abc", "def" ],
   "stats": { ... },
   "ok" : 1
}
```

The equivalent PHP implementation with iteration follows:

```
<?php
...
$whereClause = array("name" => "pippo");
$filenames = $db->command(
    array(
        "distinct" => "Data",
        "key" => "filename", 
        "query" => $whereClause
    )
);  

foreach ($filenames['values'] as $filename) {
    $result1 = var_export($filename, true);
    echo "value2: ".$result1;
    $output[] = $result1;
    echo "</br>";
}

?>
```